# How to recover overwritten saves on the Xbox 360

Tags: xbox-360, lego-movie

Today, my friend got confused and clicked new save on the Lego Movie video game and then clicked my save that had all my progress. This overwrote the save, and my progress was destroyed. Is there any way to recover the overwritten save?

Comment: You haven't defined what you mean by "weird hacks", but I'm going to assume it would include any save game recovery tools and services that could work. There isn't a magic "undo overwrite save" button.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think that (unless you backed up your save, maybe to the Cloud and didn't overwrite that) you lost that save.

Comment: I am currently unaware of being able to make multiple saves